# Grails pre-authenticated scenario

Tags: grails, spring-security, pre-authentication

I'm trying to configure a Grails app in a [pre-authenticated scenario](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html), using Spring Security Core.

So I wrote a custom authentication filter:

```
class MyAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
    protected getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(request) { "my_username" }
    protected getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(request) { "N/A" }
}
```

added it to Spring:

```
beans = {
    myAuthenticationFilter(MyAuthenticationFilter) {
        authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
        checkForPrincipalChanges = true
    }
}
```

and registered it in BootStrap, with position PRE_AUTH_FILTER:

```
class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
        SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('myAuthenticationFilter',
            SecurityFilterPosition.PRE_AUTH_FILTER.order)
    }
}
```

Config.groovy only has the standard User, Role, and UserRole class names, plus some staticRules.

Inside the filter, I tried returning all sorts of things from its `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal()` method: the user id, the user id as a string, its username, the User object itself… I can see that my filter is being called for each request (which is what I want, having set `checkForPrincipalChanges = true`) no matter what I return from it, the current user remains anonymous: `springSecurityService.principal` is still `__grails.anonymous.user__`

What do I need to change in my setup, to be able to authenticate my users, with their existing groups and roles? I don't want to write an additional authentication provider, I'm fine with Grails's standard `daoAuthenticationProvider`. Do I need to return something specific from my filter? Do I need to setup some other Spring classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. I'm documenting it here in case somebody else needs to do the same.

Basically the missing piece was to configure a new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider as the only provider. No additional code needed, just define it in resources:

```
myAuthenticationProvider(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider) {
    preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService = ref('authenticationUserDetailsService')
}
```

and set it as the only provider in Config:

```
grails.plugin.pringsecurity.providerNames = ['myAuthenticationProvider']
```

Then, from the authentication filter, just return the username of the pre-authenticated user, or null if none (the anonymous user.)